QGIS 3.40 The grid in map layout not displaying DMS even if change to EPSG:4326
I'm trying to create a grid with coordinates showing DMS. The area of my location is quite small i.e 1:16000 scale. I also change the project to EPSG:4326-WGS 84. Only When I change it to EPSG:3857-WGS 84 the coordinate appears in Decimal which I don't want.

To me, the question is not clear. Plese provide more information about what you exactly want to achieve.

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Your Question would be clearer if you detail the exact procedure you are using and include a picture of your result, annotated with what you want changed.
